# What does the term 'high voltage' really mean?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, potential, terminology, voltage

This might be a dumb question but i am not so familiar with the word voltage:

What does the textbooks really mean when they say high voltage?. Does that mean:

1. There are more charges so more voltage, or
2. If the negative charge (electron) is at a large distance from the nucleus (positive charge) as we derive for point charges.

Also, how does generators/batteries provide high voltage?, they do by gathering more charge? OR pushing electron(s) away from positive ion? (if yes, then how?)

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109424/discussion-between-doubtnut-and-user).

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify the question. 'High voltage' is not rigorously defined in physics - its just higher than what you think is appropriate. Your car's 12V DC system is low compared with your house's 120/240V AC supply, but both will be laughed at by power distribution folks used to dealing with 6kV and up. And that will be laughed at by some of us with multi MV accelerators.

Answer (score 0):

The DC voltage of a battery is determined by the number of chemical “cells” which are connected in series inside. (A 12 volt car battery has 6 cells.)  An AC alternator with fixed output coils can be designed to give a relatively high voltage, but very high AC voltages are usually attained using some sort of inductive transformer. In alternators or transformers electrons are pushed around a circuit by a changing magnetic flux.